# Finding max - SQL

Tags: sql

I needed to print ( show ) the max of the table created by the following code:

```
SELECT name, SUM(cost)+SUM(DISTINCT stock*cost) AS result 
FROM publishers 
   NATURAL JOIN editions 
   NATURAL JOIN shipments 
   NATURAL JOIN stock 
GROUP BY name
```

I have tried using DESC but am not allowed to use it

Comment: Max result I guess.. Per name or just the single max?  Side note, we'll just have to assume the rest of your query is correct without sample data.

Comment: Which RDBMS? And: please explain what you're going to approach? I don't understand it at all

Comment: Have you tried MAX?

Comment: please specify the input tables' columns and the value you want as output. the question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(result) from (SELECT name, SUM(cost)+SUM(DISTINCT stock*cost) AS result FROM publishers NATURAL JOIN editions NATURAL JOIN shipments NATURAL JOIN stock group by name )
```

This nested query should do if you only need max of `result`.